# how to make owl carousel appear in all the pages of the blog

Tags: css, owl-carousel

im really new at this but made owl carousel appear at the main page of my blog just the way i like it.

the thing is, now i want it to appear the same way in all the pages of the blog. is there a way i can make the call in the pages or anything i can add to the theme or main page so it can show it in all the articles?

i have it in the html of the theme like this

```
    * ######## Top Feature Css ######################### */
.recent-boxes .carousel {
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 0 0!important;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: visible;
    height: auto;
    display: block;
    clear: both
}
.owl-carousel .animated {
    -webkit-animation-duration: 1000ms;
    animation-duration: 1000ms;
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
    animation-fill-mode: both
}
.owl-carousel .owl-animated-in {
    z-index: 0
}
.owl-carousel .owl-animated-out {
    z-index: 1
}
.owl-carousel .fadeOut {
    -webkit-animation-name: fadeOut;
    animation-name: fadeOut
}
@-webkit-keyframes fadeOut {
    0% {
        opacity: 1
    }
    100% {
        opacity: 0
    }
}
@keyframes fadeOut {
    0% {
        opacity: 1
    }
    100% {
        opacity: 0
    }
}
.owl-height {
    -webkit-transition: height 500ms ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: height 500ms ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: height 500ms ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: height 500ms ease-in-out;
    transition: height 500ms ease-in-out
}
.owl-carousel {
    display: none;
    width: 100%;
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1
}
.owl-carousel .owl-stage {
    position: relative;
    -ms-touch-action: pan-Y
}
.owl-carousel .owl-stage:after {
    content: ".";
    display: block;
    clear: both;
    visibility: hidden;
    line-height: 0;
    height: 0
}
.owl-carousel .owl-stage-outer {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px)
}
.owl-carousel .owl-controls .owl-nav .owl-prev,
.owl-carousel .owl-controls .owl-nav .owl-next,
.owl-carousel .owl-controls .owl-dot {
    cursor: pointer;
    cursor: hand;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none
}
.owl-carousel.owl-loaded {
    display: block
}
.owl-carousel.owl-loading {
    opacity: 0;
    display: block
}
.owl-carousel.owl-hidden {
    opacity: 0
}
.owl-carousel .owl-refresh .owl-item {
    display: none
}
.owl-carousel .owl-item {
    position: relative;
    min-height: 1px;
    float: left;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none
}
.owl-carousel .owl-item img {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d
}
.owl-carousel.owl-text-select-on .owl-item {
    -webkit-user-select: auto;
    -moz-user-select: auto;
    -ms-user-select: auto;
    user-select: auto
}
.owl-carousel .owl-grab {
    cursor: move;
    cursor: -webkit-grab;
    cursor: -o-grab;
    cursor: -ms-grab;
    cursor: grab
}
.owl-carousel.owl-rtl {
    direction: rtl
}
.owl-carousel.owl-rtl .owl-item {
    float: right
}
.no-js .owl-carousel {
    display: block
}
.owl-prev,
.owl-next {
    top: 0;
    color: #fff;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
    font-family: FontAwesome;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    display: block;
    padding: 0;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: center;
    overflow: hidden
}
.owl-prev {
    left: 0
}
.owl-prev:before {
    content: "\f104"
}
.owl-next {
    right: 0
}
.owl-next:before {
    content: "\f105"
}
.owl-prev:hover,
.owl-next:hover {
    background-color: #000
}
.owl-dots {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 1px;
    width: 33.33%;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: auto;
    text-align: center
}
.owl-dot {
    background: #fff;
    height: 3px;
    width: 10px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 2px;
    -moz-border-radius: 2px;
    border-radius: 2px;
    opacity: .6
}
.owl-dot.active,
.owl-dot:hover {
    background: #e74c3c
}
.main-carousel {
    height: 350px;
    overflow: hidden
}
.main-carousel .owl-item {
    width: 100%;
}
.carousel-item {
    height: 350px;
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    padding: 0!important;
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden
}
.carousel-item .box-image {
    height: 350px;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    display: block
}
.carousel-item .box-image:after {
    content: no-close-quote;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 151px;
    background: url(http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-LnvazGBvKh8/VskckSkmzxI/AAAAAAAAC4s/erEgI6A_ih4/s1600-r/metabg.png) repeat-x;
    opacity: .8
}
.carousel-content {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 2;
    box-sizing: border-box
}
.carousel-item .carousel-content {
    padding: 15px;
    text-align: center;
}
.carousel-item .recent-title {
    margin: 10px 0 5px;
    font-size: 19px;
    font-weight: 400
}
.carousel-item .recent-title a {
    color: #fff;
    display: block;
    line-height: 1.4em;
    text-shadow: 0 .5px .5px rgba(34, 34, 34, 0.3)
}
.carousel-item .recent-author {
    color: #fff;
}
.carousel-item .recent-date {
    visibility: hidden;
    display: none;
}
.carousel-tag a {
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: #e74c3c;
    color: #fff;
    height: 20px;
    line-height: 20px;
    padding: 0 6px;
    font-size: 11px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    border-radius: 2px
}
.carousel-tag a:before {
    content: "\f091";
font-family: FontAwesome;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-style: normal;
    line-height: 1;
    padding-right: 4px;
}
.recent-author::before {
    content: '\f007';
    font-family: fontawesome;
    color: #bbb;
    margin-right: 5px;
}
.recent-author {
    margin-right: 10px;
}
.carousel-overlay {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 1;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: rgba(40, 35, 40, 0.05)
}
.main-carousel .owl-item:hover .carousel-overlay {
    background-color: $mainbgcolor;
opacity:0.5;
}
.carousel-overlay:before {
z-index: 3;
border-top: 1px solid #fff;
border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
-webkit-transform: scale(0,1);
transform: scale(0,1);
}
.carousel-overlay:after {
z-index: 3;
border-right: 1px solid #fff;
border-left: 1px solid #fff;
-webkit-transform: scale(1,0);
transform: scale(1,0);
}
.carousel-overlay:before, .carousel-overlay:after {
z-index: 3;
position: absolute;
top: 10px;
right: 10px;
bottom: 10px;
left: 10px;
content: '';
opacity: 0;
-webkit-transition: opacity 0.5s, -webkit-transform 0.5s;
transition: opacity 0.5s, transform 0.5s;
}
.main-carousel .owl-item:hover .carousel-overlay:before, .main-carousel .owl-item:hover .carousel-overlay:after {
opacity: 1;
-webkit-transform: scale(1);
transform: scale(1);
}

.main-carousel .owl-prev,
.main-carousel .owl-next {
    margin-top: 0px;
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    font-size: 25px;
    line-height: 40px
}
.main-carousel .owl-prev {
    left: -50px
}
.main-carousel:hover .owl-prev {
    left: 0
}
.main-carousel .owl-next {
    right: -50px
}
.main-carousel:hover .owl-next {
    right: 0
}
.main-carousel .owl-dots {
    bottom: 10px
}
```